# Get route parameters in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
<Route path="chats/:id" element={<Chat />} />
```

```
import React from "react";

export default class Chat extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.match.params.id}
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

If I use this, I only get a white site and the following error:

```
Chat.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
    at Chat.render (Chat.js:6:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:20487:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:20433:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22366:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4157:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4206:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4270:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27243:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26392:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26303:1)
```

How can I get this to work?
No tutorial or googling worked.

(*I use react-router-dom v6*)

Comment: [See the docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#reading-url-parameters)

Comment: Hey, u shoud wrap class component into `withRouter` function (if you are using a version older than v6)

Comment: @moonwave99 I don't use functions. I use classes.

Comment: @LevayaPochta I use v6.

Comment: @Jak2k, Then you need to write a wrapper over the class component and pass the props from there

Comment: Check [this](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it) from docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react-router@v6 docs provide a wrapper

```
// withRouter.js
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}
export default withRouter
```

Then just use it

```
import React from "react";
import withRouter from './withRouter';

export default withRouter(class Chat extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <>
        {this.props.router.params.id}
      </>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried it, but:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Comment: @Jak2k, Sorry didn't notice, use `this.props.router.params.id`

Comment: how to use in typescript ? please provide type names

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend using the `useParams` hook for this use case. You'd have to use a functional component though. It would end up looking like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

export default function Chat() {
  const params= useParams()

  return <>{params.id}</> 
}
```

Comment: I always disliked how new React versions try to force developers to use functional components. In their documentation, they try to say the opposite, and try to be nice. But in reality, in many cases they leave no other option but to switch to functional compoments. The OP showed an example with a class based component, and got back an answer with a functional component. I'm not criticising too much here, but it would be nice to show a solution with a class based component.

Comment: I appreciate the criticism, but I came here searching for an answer for my functional component and didn't find one, so once I figured it out on my end I came back here to provide this alternative solution to help others who may have landed here like I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use withRouter to accomplish this. Simply wrap your exported classed component inside of withRouter and then you can use this.props.match.params.id to get the parameters

import withRouter from react router v5

```js
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
```

wrap your class component with withRouter

```js
import React from "react";

class Chat extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.match.params.id}
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Chat)
```

for react router v6 use custom wrapper

```js
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}
```

react router v6 [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq)

Comment: export 'withRouter' (imported as 'withRouter') was not found in 'react-router' (possible exports: MemoryRouter, Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, Routes, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, createPath, createRoutesFromChildren, generatePath, matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, renderMatches, resolvePath, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLocation, useMatch, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRoutes)