# get the url params in a class component router V6 react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I've updated my project from router v5 to v6. now I can't read the URL params using `queryString.parse(this.window.location)`

is there a way to get the parameters in a class component router V6? following is my code.

**App.js**

```
function App(){
    return(
     <Routes>
       <Route path="/bookingSummary" element={<BookingSummary/>}/>
     </Routes>
    )}
```

**bookingSummary.js(class component)**

```
componentDidMount() {
 movieInfo = queryString.parse(this.window.location)
}
```

Comment: Check this link. Hope it helps you

https://stackoverflow.com/q/69967745/11399221

Comment: @Arman i don't understand this scenario Drew Reese has mentioned.. 

Comment: either you can convert the Class component to a functional component. Or you need to use Higher Order Component to access URL params. You also need to install react-router-dom to access URL params.

Comment: @Arman i'm using react-router-dom v6. so how could I get params in class component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get route parameters in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71817693/get-route-parameters-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what `queryString` is I think you might only need to pass the `search` string from the `window.location` object, e.g. `queryString.parse(this.window.location.search)`.

You should use the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) hook though to access the queryString parameters object. If you are using a class-based component you'll still need to either convert to a React function component in order to use the React hooks, or utilize the custom `withRouter` implementation to access the queryString params and inject that also as props.

Example:

```
import { useSearchParams, /* other hooks */ } from 'react-router-dom';

const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  // etc... other react-router-dom v6 hooks

  return (
    <WrappedComponent
      {...props}
      {...{ searchParams, setSearchParams, /* other injected props */} }
    />
  );
};
```

Decorate the `BookingSummary` component.

```
export default withRouter(BookingSummary);
```

Access the injected props.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { searchParams } = this.props;
  const movieInfo = searchParams.get("movieInfo");

  ...
}
```